# Switching from NGUI to UGUI?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

I’ve been using NGUI for years and I’m thinking of switching to UGUI.

Does anyone know well-known games that have been developed using UGUI? I know a lot that have used NGUI but not sure about UGUI. I’d like to see if the games are good.

I would appreciate any input.

Comment: Some games don't mention that they were made with Unity so you will never know. Right now, the only advantage of using NGUI is the default sprites that comes with it. It makes it easier to make a nice UI without putting much effort. UGUI's default sprites are just plain white images. This really shouldn't matter if you are or have an artist.

Comment: Or hell, even if you spend twenty minutes in paint you can generally whip up some decent looking uGUI sprites. All you need to know is how 9 slice scaling works. [Panel](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/Textures/gui/basic-window.png), [Button](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/Textures/gui/button.png), [Tooltip](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/Textures/gui/tooltip_window.png), [Inset](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/Textures/gui/inner.png)... Modeled after the Minecraft asthetic.

Comment: `Unity UI` is the best option. It's improving all the time and will guarantee compatibility going forward. It will also benefit from engine optimizations and threading while `NGUI` won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know any well known games made using uGUI but u can check some of the games which i helped develop and they are using uGUI.

[Jump and Rush](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jump-rush-jungle-fever/id1077412523?mt=8&lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_profile_view_base%3BszErjcEkSbygTm%2FDy%2ByK8g%3D%3D)

[Poptropica](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.pearsoned.poptropica&hl=en&lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_profile_view_base%3BszErjcEkSbygTm%2FDy%2ByK8g%3D%3D)

I also switched from NGUI to uGUI back when Unity 4.6 was released. At the time i felt NGUI was still better and uGUI just lacked many of the features that NGUI had. Now i feel uGUI is better. Still some tools i extracted from NGUI which uGUI lacked and edited it to support unity UI. Those were tween library and some editor tools. Of course we have iTween, leantween, etc. but interface which NGUI provided through inspector was better.

I suggest you to switch to uGUI. Everything possible with NGUI is possible with uGUI also and it is much more efficient performance wise also. It is open source
like NGUI .

Check this link for source : bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll definitely consider UGUI for my next game.